# Isolating String between 3 Characters

Tags: sql-server, parsing

I have a view where I would like to create a column that isolates a string between 3 of the same character ("-"). So for example, I want `AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1` to become `RBQ/4110`.

So far I have tried this and it gets me very close.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(locnum,CHARINDEX('-',locnum)+1,(((LEN(locnum))-CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(locnum)))-CHARINDEX('-',locnum))) AS Result
```

Result:

```
RBQ/4110-WS
RBQ/4110-CS
```

I just need to remove that last "-WS" or "-CS"

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The data should be stored in separate columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pattern is consistent, perhaps `parsename()` would be a good fit here

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(100) = 'AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1'

Select parsename(replace(@S,'-','.'),3)
```

**Returns**

```
RBQ/4110
```

> **EDIT -**

Just in case your data is more variable, you can use XML to extract the **SECOND** value

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (locnum varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1')

Select NewValue = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(locnum,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
RBQ/4110
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem simpler to split the value and then extract the 2nd item from your data. If your data always has 4 elements (and you always need the second), you could use `PARSENAME`:

```
SELECT PN.P
FROM (VALUES('AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1'))V(S)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PARSENAME(REPLACE(V.S,'-','.'),3)))PN(P); --Part 3 as PARSENAME works right to left
```

Otherwise you could use a splitter like [`delimitedsplit8k_lead`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2):

```
SELECT DS.Item
FROM (VALUES('AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1'))V(S)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_lead(V.S,'-') DS
WHERE DS.ItemNumber = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below Query. If your pattern is same per your question then below will work.

```
select left(SUBSTRING('AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1', charindex('-','AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1') + 1, LEN('AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1')),8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done most of the work and you need to get the left part of the result up to `-`:

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(SUBSTRING(locnum, CHARINDEX('-', locnum) + 1,
  (((LEN(locnum)) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(locnum))) - CHARINDEX('-', locnum))),
  CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(locnum, CHARINDEX('-', locnum) + 1,
  (((LEN(locnum)) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(locnum))) - CHARINDEX('-', locnum)))) - 1) AS Result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TEMP AS
(
SELECT 'AC-RBQ/4110-WS-L1'  AS COL
)

SELECT * ,
CHARINDEX('-', [COL]) AS FR,
CHARINDEX('-', [COL],CHARINDEX('-', [COL])+1) AS FR2,
SUBSTRING([COL], CHARINDEX('-', [COL]) +1 ,CHARINDEX('-', [COL],CHARINDEX('- 
', [COL])+1) - (CHARINDEX('-', [COL]) +1) ) AS RESULT
FROM TEMP
```